# How to insert the first element of the map looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, fetch-api

The source is from "https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js/issues". And some of the "labels.name" contain 1 or more array. And I want to make this code which is :

```
function fetchData() {
  fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js/issues")
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error("ERROR");
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((test) => {
      console.log(test);
      const html = test
        .map((user) => {
          return `
            <ul id="myUL">
              <div style="min-height: 50px;">
                <div class="card card-body" style="width: 100%;">
                  <li><a href="#">
                  ${user.title}
                  <button>
                  ${user.labels.map((label, index) => {
                    if (index === 0) {
                      return `
                        ${label.name}
                      `;
                    }
                  })}
                  </button>
                  <button>
                  ${user.labels.map((label, index) => {
                    if (index === 1) {
                      return `
                        ${label.name}
                      `;
                    }
                  })}
                  </button>
                  <button>
                  ${user.labels.map((label, index) => {
                    if (index === 2) {
                      return `
                        ${label.name}
                      `;
                    }
                  })}
                  </button>
                  </a></li>  
                </div>
              </div>
          </ul>
          `;
        })
        .join("");
      console.log(html);
      document.querySelector("#app").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

fetchData();

function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

when i tried to use code : ${label.name[0]} to only take the first array only, it only show the first word of the array instead. How to make it only show up the first array only, 2nd array only while keep looping?

Comment: Hi, do you wanna show the first element of labels? ``` <div>
        {data.map((user, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {user.labels.map((label) => {
              if (index === 0) {
                return <button key={label.name}>{label.name}</button>;
              }
            })}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>``` could you try like that? here is an example [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-mountain-tt92p9?file=/src/App.js:533-823)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly you want you can do an condition using index.

```
${user.labels.map((label,index) => {
  if (index===0){
    return `
        ${label.name}
    `;
  }
 // keep looping here
 return;
 })
```

Comment: airight let me try that

Comment: it did work wonder. But for weird reason, it added coma "," for no reason like :
template:bug , - 
, area: app - 
type: next ,,

Comment: Check your code, maybe you add the "," or leave the code and we can take a look :)

Comment: ok let me put my full code real quick

Comment: i sent my full code now. I dont think i saw any comma there

Comment: I didn't see any comma neither, it is possible that the "label.name" have the commas??

Comment: i dont think thats the case. Like if u see from the api link itself, the comma there represent to move to other array. Huh its really weird

Comment: Though for now what i asked before did work wonder. Now I just need to find a way to remove that comma...

Comment: also i need to find a way to remove the "button" that dont have any text in it...

Comment: I found the way to remove the comma. IDK why it's there for no reason, I just have to use join("") to remove the seperator which is comma in this case.